# Página com Scroll Suave

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, rolamento

Estou linkando as páginas para fazer um scroll suave entre os links internos mas não está dando certo.

**Javascript**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('nav a').click(function(e)){
      e.preventDefault();
      var id = $(this).attr('href');
        targetOffset = $(id).offset().top;
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop:targetOffset
      },500)

      }
      </script>
```

**MENU HTML**

```
<header>
        <div class="menu">
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" >página principal</a><i class="fas fa-home fa-2x" title="Página Principal"></i></li>
                <li><a href="#atendimento" >atendimento</a><i class="fas fa-book-reader fa-2x" title="Atendimento"></i></li>
                <li><a href="#sobremim" >sobre mim</a><i class="far fa-smile fa-2x" title="Sobre mim"></i></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
        </div>
</header>
```

**CONTEÚDO HTML**

```
<div class="row featurette">
          <div class="col-md-7 order-md-2" id="sobremim">
            <h2 class="featurette-heading" id="sobremim">Sobre mim</h2>
            <p class="lead">texto</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5 order-md-1">
              <img class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" src="/img/sala.jpg">          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em seu CSS coloque o código

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

E não irá precisar do código Javascript.

Comment: O Safari ainda não suporta essa propriedade.

Answer (score 2):

Existe um método em elementos HTML chamado `.scrollIntoView(scrollIntoViewOptions)`.

Com ele, é possível fazer o navegador rolar a página até o elemento.
O `scrollIntoViewOptions` é um objeto que aceita a propriedade `"behavior": "smooth"`, que faz o navegador rolar suavemente até ele.

No seu caso, ficaria assim:

```
$('nav a').click(function(e)){
    this.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}
```